# Can AWS Signed URLs check for duplicate images

Tags: amazon-s3, signed, pre-signed-url

My team is currently replacing an image upload operation that is handled in Node JS, with a a straight to S3 strategy using signed URLs. We currently check for duplicate images as part of that upload operation. Is it possible to do the same using signed URLs?

The reason is that our payloads are pretty large, and we use Heroku as a PAAS. Heroku times out after 30 seconds, so we are by-passing Heroku and uploading straight to S3.

The only thing that will be missing with the 'signed url' 'straight to S3' strategy is that our Node server can tell if an image is *already uploaded*. Before we upload, we hash the image's content and rename this image this hash (i.e. `a812ne12812e891213123w3.png`). We do a HEAD request to see if an image named `a812ne12812e891213123w3.png` exists, **if it does exist**, we just return that URL and do not upload the file. If it doesn't exist, we upload the file.

I'm relatively new using signed URLs, and am wondering if something similar can be done using signed URLs?

Comment: How do you generate the presigned URL? If it's the backend generating it, how does the backend know what the image hash is?

Comment: Yes, we have an Express server. We plan to upload the image's names and extensions to an endpoint. From there (using the S3 secrets) we'll sign the images with the rules we'll define (i.e. limit to POST for 1 minute)

Comment: Why not check for image existence before you issue the presigned URL in the backend?

Comment: Yes that's true